# cluster validation and determining number of clusters

Tags: graph-theory, graphing-functions, spectral-graph-theory, clustering

I want to find number of cluster in the real world data set. So, I validate the spectral clustering by using some indexes as shown in figures below? But as you seen in figures the results are very different from one index to other. How to determine the good number of clusters in the spectral clustering method? If u don't have complete answer give me any suggestion or idea that may help me.

Thanks
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe there exists no best method to assess clustering quality, independently of the data. You can check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15376075/cluster-analysis-in-r-determine-the-optimal-number-of-clusters) for many other ways to assess such quality, in the case of k-means. Thiscan be good starting point: the relationship between spectral clustering and a suitable generalization of k-means is contained [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_clustering) .An important discrimination in quality assessment is between internal and external methods: internal ones check the dependence of an objective function on the number of clusters (for example, this is what happens with the "elbow" method). External criteria refer to an optimal "choice", which has to be known a priori, and try to compare the optimum with the computed clustering. The optimal choice has to be inferred looking at the data, knowing the problem in detail, or by other methods. In your specific case, different methods seem to give quite different answers. I would try now to visualize the clusters, and to find and select the choice which gives the most reasonable classification of the data themselves.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I agree with your description but as you mentioned I give quite different answers and don't know how to conclude from them and I should mention that my data is about 5k*5k and it is very difficult to visualize and analyse the data.

Comment: you are welcome. Please, feel free to flag the answer if you found it useful. Returning to your analysis: I have noticed you did not include the silhouette coefficient: is there any reason for that? More than the sheer number of data, I would have a look at the origin of them, their structure and so on. Try to select 2 features and make a plot of the clusters.

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by "I have noticed you did not include the silhouette coefficient: is there any reason for that?"

Comment: In many cluster packages you can compute the silhouette coefficient of the obtained clustering. I was just wondering whether you excluded it from the above list of indices due to theoretical reasons.

Comment: I found also this answer for you :-) It is quite interesting. I hope it helps http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/65712/verifying-the-output-of-implementing-internal-clustering-validity-indexes

Comment: Thanks :-). As you see in question silhouette coefficient is the first one that I check it. Thanks for link I didn't see it. yes, it is interesting.

Comment: My features data is so sparse and there are many features for spectral clustering. May it cause problem? Do the results that I obtained are natural?

Comment: Ooops...my bad: I did not recognize the silhoutte at a first glance! Sparsity can be a critical feature of data...see for example the answers in http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10122/looking-for-sparse-and-high-dimensional-clustering-implementation?rq=1

Comment: @Thanks again.Yes,It is. I think you don't see it because I load many graphs :-)...

Comment: No problem! Please tell me if you need more info, ok? Otherwise I would close this thread asking for a flag of the answer if it was useful :-)